# select columns in pandas dataframe based on other columns value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select A,B,C columns row where D columns value is 1.
in sql i can use this :

```
select A,B,C
from table
where D = 1
```

How can i convert this in pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `loc`:

```
print(df.loc[df['D'] == 1, ['A', 'B', 'C']])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use another way and don't use `loc` like below:

```
df[df['D']==1][['A','B','C']]
```

Comment: @SädnänMøhøsïn if this is correct and help you please read this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Well this is less efficient tho...

Comment: My answer with `loc` is much more efficient because that would extract from each row instead of constructing the whole dataframe then getting the specific columns @SädnänMøhøsïn

Comment: @U12-Forward two answer work as same. this is not good for getting `accept` say Contrary to reality. two answer work this : `extract from each row instead of constructing the whole dataframe`

Comment: @SädnänMøhøsïn no matter you `accept` which answer but both answers work as same. I mention this that you know. both answer first find df['D']==1 then return column `A,B,C` exactly what you want and say in your question.